# C# - Redrawing Client Area with transparency

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, transparency, gdi

I need to render only the Client Area of a Control (TextBox) on winforms with transparency using GDI, because GDI+ doesn't support transparency for dynamic controls. I've already searched a lot, for two days, and founded two links:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162910(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/transparency.html

I think if i join these two solutions, i can obtain what i want, but i don't know how to put them in code. Someone could help me please?

I tried use AlphaBlend, but is not working, here is my code:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case PranchetaApp.Prancheta.Utils.GDIWrapper.WM_PAINT:

                Bitmap memBmp = new Bitmap(this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

                IntPtr memdc = PranchetaApp.Prancheta.Utils.GDIWrapper.CreateCompatibleDC(this.CreateGraphics().GetHdc());
                PranchetaApp.Prancheta.Utils.GDIWrapper.SelectObject(memdc, memBmp.GetHbitmap());

                Graphics memDC = Graphics.FromHdc(memdc);
                Graphics clientDC = this.CreateGraphics();
                memDC.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), 0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height);

                IntPtr hdc = clientDC.GetHdc();
                IntPtr hMemdc = memDC.GetHdc();
                //PranchetaApp.Prancheta.Utils.GDIWrapper.BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height, hMemdc, 0, 0, PranchetaApp.Prancheta.Utils.GDIWrapper.SRCCOPY);

                PranchetaApp.Prancheta.Utils.GDIWrapper.BLENDFUNCTION bfn;
                bfn.AlphaFormat = 0;
                bfn.BlendFlags = 0;
                bfn.BlendOp = 0;
                bfn.SourceConstantAlpha = 0;

                PranchetaApp.Prancheta.Utils.GDIWrapper.AlphaBlend(hdc, 0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height, hMemdc, 0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Height, this.ClientRectangle.Height, bfn);

                clientDC.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
                memDC.ReleaseHdc(hMemdc);

                break;

            default:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thats not really what this site does, give it a try and come back when you can't make it work, at least show some effort to do this. Also a better description of what you are trying to do would help, as it may be an X-Y problem and there could be an easier/better answer.

Comment: Ok, i'm really really sorry, but i have no ideia what to do. I don't want the code, i just need same help, how to put the solution together, at least to know if i'm going on right way. I've already tried a lot of codes and soluitons but nothis its working.

Comment: Can you explain what it is you are trying to do? You want to redraw a textbox with transparency, but what kind of transparency? Just slightly transparent with the form behind it, or like a hole in the form all the way to the desktop? Also what do you mean by "dynamic controls"? Please explain in detail of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have a soccer field, that's a control. A need to put over this field, a TextBox, but the ClientArea of the TextBox need to have a transparent background while i'm tapping the text. If a just put the TextBox on field and use some usual solution (like this one: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6f48c005-2ddf-4669-9c0a-6fe11c0b235f/how-to-make-a-textbox-transparent), it works, but when i need to render the control again, it doenst working anymore.

Comment: Have you tried telling the textbox to redraw (invalidate) after you render the soccer field?

Comment: Yes, i tried. But like this link say: http://theartofdev.com/2013/10/24/transparent-text-rendering-with-gdi/ , GDI doenst support completely alpha channel. I believe i need to render a Bitmap with transparency to a HDC memory, then use BitBlt to copy back to Handler, what i could not implement ;/

Comment: @user3119197 I posted 2 links about Transparent `TextBox` written in C#, Hope you find it helpful

Comment: @user3119197 Let me know if you find those links helpful:)

Comment: Ok, thank you, i already tried both of them, the second link did not work but now i will try the firts link again, to read the concepts without API.

Comment: I posted my code, but is not working =/